# Shell command for $

Tags: shell, command-line, directory

I using script to apply folder permission. The script is working fine for applying permission.
On the script I just need to key in the complete path of directory.

However I meet challenge where the directory name is using `$`. e.g. `G:\$Tobe-Review`

Mean while on the script:

```
$PATH = "G:\$Tobe-Review"
```

The output of course give an error.

How to counter the `$` sign for the folder name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the single-quote to prevent from interpolate the `$`. [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) might be very helpful to you to understand the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your path in single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

```
$PATH = 'G:\$Tobe-Review'
```